# Página php, Não Salva No Banco ! Porque?

Tags: php, sql

O código abaixo esta dentro de uma enorme página, necessito que o valor que a pessoa colocar em "email" seja inserido na variável e assim ao banco.Já revisei milhares de códigos distintos porém sempre continua com o mesmo problema **Não grava no banco**, a conexão esta estabelecida (sem sombra de erros). Já revisei o código várias vezes, mas não consigo resolver o problema.

```
<div id="boxes">

<!-- Janela Modal com caixa de diálogo -->  
<div id="dialog1" class="window">
  <div class="d-header">

    <form method="POST" action="?go=cadastrar">
    <img src="imagem.png">
        <h3>Digite seu E-mail e comece GRÁTIS !!</h3>
        <label>Consiga agora o incrível programa que irá lhe ajudar!</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required value="E-mail" 
placeholder="E-mail" onclick="this.value=''" maxlength="60" /></a><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="Enviado">
        <input type="submit" name="cadastro" id="cadastro" value="Cadastrar" 
onclick="javascript:window.open('download.php?file=apostila_JAVA.pdf')"/>
<br/>

        <a href="http://echef.teccitystore.com.br/downloads.html" 
 name="fechar">Fechar[x]</a>
   <img src="logo.png">
 </form>
  </div>
  <div class="d-blank"></div>
</div>
<!-- Fim Janela Modal com caixa de diálogo -->  
</div>

<!-- Máscara para cobrir a tela -->
  <div id="mask"></div>


 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['go'])){
  if($_GET['go'] == 'cadastrar'){
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if(empty($email)){
        echo"
            <script>
            alert('Campo está vazio');
            history.back();
            </script
        ";
    }else{
        $query1 = @msql_fetch_row(@msql_query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE = 
'$email'"));
        if($query1 == 1){
            echo "<script>
            alert('Email já existente !!');
            history.back();
           </script";
        }else{
            @mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloads (email) VALUES ('email')");
            echo "<script>
            alert('Cadastro Efetuado !!');
            history.back();
            </script";
            header("location: index.php");
            }
        }
     }
}
  ?>
```

Comment: Primeira coisa que você deve fazer é remover os "@" das conexões com o MySQL. Depois execute novamente e veja se aconteceu algum erro via mysql_error.

Comment: ele.. não mostra erros.. apenas não aparece no banco.. é como se os dados sumissem do nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique os comandos SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM email WHERE = '" . $email . "' ";

$insert = "INSERT INTO downloads (email) VALUES ('" . email . "')";
```

Verifique também o fechamento da tag SCRIPT.

Se o if empty não funcionar, tenta (email != '') que pode te ajudar mais com a lógica em si.

Comment: eu Executei tudo oque disse.. porém ele diz que -->
Erro de análise: erro de sintaxe, fim inesperado do arquivo em C: \ wamp64 \ www \ pagina \ downloads.php na linha 951

Comment: e o que tem na linha 951?

Comment: O final... </html>

Comment: inclui mais um } antes do ?> e vê se roda.

Comment: Conseguiii.. hyoooo.. kk .. Obrigada.. Mas ainda sim, Não esta inserindo no banco.. ele mostra pelo JavaScript que o cadastro foi efetuado.. porém não esta no banco

Comment: Deve ter uma pasta de logs em "C:\wamp64\" com os erros que dão no aplicativo. Nesses logs você encontra o erro absoluto que ocorre na execução. Apesar de no lado cliente você ver que teve erro, pode ter ocorrido algo do lado do servidor.

Comment: Entendido.. Obrigada.. irei tentar por lá.. agradeço muito sua ajuda.. e desculpa se fiz algo errado.. sou nova nisso ...Obrigadaa

Answer (score 0):

Olhando seu código em query1 há um erro na string sql na condição do WHERE:

```
$query1 = @msql_fetch_row(@msql_query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE = 
'$email'"));
```

Altere ela para:

```
$query1 = @mysql_fetch_row(@msql_query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE email = 
'$email'"));
```

e também altere a string de insert de:

```
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloads (email) VALUES ('email')");
```

para:

```
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloads (email) VALUES ( $email)");
```

Dando uma olhada rápida foi o que achei que poderia estar dando erro. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Fiz como aconselhou... porém ele não insere no banco.. esta voltando normalmente.. como se tivesse inserido.. se lhe faltar alguma coisa, por favor me avise e tentarei lhe mostrar o mais detalhadamente que conseguir..

Comment: Retire os @ da frente das chamadas das funções, se tiver algum erro vai aparecer na tela. Essas @ suprimem qualquer erro que estiver acontecendo dificultando a depuração do código.

Comment: eu tirei... juro..  e não mostra nenhum erro

Comment: Experimente usar a função mysql_error() e veja se tem alguma saida.

Comment: Ele aparece isso -> 
Erro de análise: erro de sintaxe, fim inesperado do arquivo em C: \ wamp64 \ www \ pagina \ downloads.php na linha 954... já revi e não tem nenhuma tag sozinha..

Comment: Neste momento não posso testar aonde estou, porém se você enviar seu código completo mais tarde quando chegar em casa posso testar o código completo. Envia seu código para o pastebin e posta o link aqui se achar melhor.